# Rails 4 - Javascript displaying but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

for some odd reason, my javascript is displaying when I view source but the code is not actually affecting the page. I have put all the different javascript files into the assets/javascript folder but it's not displaying. Any ideas?! Here is what different pieces of my rails 4 code look like. I

### View Source

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trakly</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/styles.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/agency.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/cbpAnimatedHeader.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/classie.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/contact_me.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jqBootstrapValidation.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-1.11.0.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

### application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trakly</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

            <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                    <%= content_tag( :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
            <% end %>

        <%= yield %>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

### **application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**Agency.js**

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Agnecy Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

**Classie.js**

```
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

**CBPAnimatedHeader**

```
/**
 * cbpAnimatedHeader.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-default' ),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 300;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
            }
        }, false );
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

**Home.html.erb**

```
<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Trakly</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#mission">Mission</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">Embark on the career that finds you!</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">Find a career track that fits you!</div>
                <a href="#mission" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Signup! Now!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

<!-- Mission -->
<section id="mission" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>About</h2>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p>Freelancer is a free bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap. The download includes the complete source files including HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well as optional LESS stylesheets for easy customization.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p>Whether you're a student looking to showcase your work, a professional looking to attract clients, or a graphic artist looking to share your projects, this template is the perfect starting point!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">About</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="timeline">
                        <li>
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/1.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>2009-2011</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>March 2011</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/3.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>December 2012</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Transition to Full Service</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/4.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                                <div class="timeline-heading">
                                    <h4>July 2014</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Phase Two Expansion</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <h4>Be Part
                                    <br>Of Our
                                    <br>Story!</h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your js and html code?

Comment: I don't think the problem is the code, because when I run it as just an html document the JS takes into effect.

Comment: @Mandeep therefore is it still necessary to see it?

Comment: You have jquery twice, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I was really hoping that was it but nah just tried it :(

Comment: @NJay well your question says js not working and i don't think anyone can debug your problem by look at your layout file or script tags :). You are using turbolinks so are you using `.on` function for firing your js?

Comment: @Mandeep okay let me put it up on github real quick

Comment: @Mandeep https://github.com/nreisch/trakly

Comment: @NJay do you see any error in browsers console when you fire js? sorry but can you add your required js and html in question itself as i don't know which js code you are talking about and what html it's using

Comment: @Mandeep the only error displayed from the console is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/img/about/4.jpg" I dont think that would cause the JS to not work though

Comment: @NJay Is there any specific code which is not working or all of your js is not working? If it's something specific then can you edit your question and add your required js and html in question itself as i don't know which js code you are talking about and what html it's using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59059/discussion-between-njay-and-mandeep).

Comment: Does the js work if you completely refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**1.Put this after your closing tag body**

```
<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'classie.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'cbpAnimatedHeader.js' %>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jqBootstrapValidation.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'contact_me.js' %>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'agency.js' %>
```

**In your code it will look like this**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trakly</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

            <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                    <%= content_tag( :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
            <% end %>

        <%= yield %>
    </div>


</body>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'classie.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'cbpAnimatedHeader.js' %>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jqBootstrapValidation.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'contact_me.js' %>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'agency.js' %>

</html>
```

**2.Remove the jquery-1.11.0 file in your assets directory**

**3.In application.js you can just leave it or remove your line of code // = require_tree . Not affect anything**

Comment: There's no evidence that anyone is using JSP pages here.